# For more than one text boxes in a tab not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, working-directory

For more than one `textboxes` in a tab this following example is not working.

#### Code

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asimshahiddIT/p7n9vdon/).

```
$(document).on('click', 'button[name="save"]', function() {
  var tabs = $('.tab-pane input');
  $('.nav.nav-tabs li,.tab-pane').removeClass('active');
  
  var bool = false;
  $.each(tabs, function(index, value) {

    if ($(this).val().length <= 0) {
      $('ul.nav li:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('active');
      $('.tab-content .tab-pane:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('active');
      $(this).focus();
      return false;
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you explain what is not working? What is the correct/expected behavior?

Comment: what do you want explain more?

Comment: what are the abc of your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The reason your example dosent work is because you are trying to access the inputs based on the tabs index. Once you add more inputs to a tab the li:eq(' + index + ') will not apply the class active to the other inputs. However, you most likely shouldn't as it would be confusing to the user if more than one input is marked as active at a time.